# Winsock send() error when sending POST request to HTTP server

Tags: c++, http, post, winsock

I can't get `send()` to return anything but `-1` when sending the `POST` string:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;

SOCKET socket_create_http()
{
    SOCKET sock;
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    struct hostent* host;

    char url[] = "domain.net";

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    host = gethostbyname(url);

    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(54000);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

    int bound = bind(sock, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr));
            
    return(sock);
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA ws_data;
    WORD ws_version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int startup = WSAStartup(ws_version, &ws_data);

    SOCKET sock_http = socket_create_http();

    string data = "action=0&data=0";

    string request_string = "POST ";
    request_string += "stuff://domain.net/script.php?";
    request_string += " HTTP/1.1\r\n"; // or HTTP/1.0
    request_string += "Host: domain.net\r\n";
    request_string += "Content-Length: " + to_string(data.size()) + "\r\n";
    request_string += "\r\n";
    request_string += data;

    int sent = send(sock_http, request_string.c_str(), strlen(request_string.c_str()), 0);
    cout << "SENT: " << sent << endl;

    closesocket(sock_http);
    return 0;
}
```

I probably need `_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS` in preprocessor definitions to run it.

I've been at this for a few days. Any ideas where I could be going wrong with the socket setup, or post format, or both?

---

**UPDATE:** I've updated my code and now I'm receiving `400 bad request` when sending the `POST` string:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;

SOCKET sock_http;

SOCKET socket_create_http(const char* hostname, unsigned short port)
{
    hostent* host = gethostbyname(hostname);

    if (host)
    {
        cout << "HTTP HOST: " << host << endl;

        SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (sock != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr = {};
            SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            SockAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
            SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(host->h_addr);

            if (connect(sock, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                cout << "HTTP SOCKET CREATED: " << sock << endl << endl;
                return sock;
            }
    
            //closesocket(sock); //safety
        }
    }
}
    
bool http_post(string data)
{
    char bb_receive[4096];
    
    ostringstream request; 
    request << "POST stuff://domain.net/script.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"; //stuff is https
    request << "Host: domain.net\r\n";
    request << "Content-Length: " << data.size() << "\r\n";
    request << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    request << "Connection: close\r\n";
    request << "\r\n";
    request << data;

    string request_string = request.str();

    size_t data_size = request_string.size();
    
    const char* pdata = static_cast<const char*>(request_string.c_str());
    
    bool all_sent = false;
    
    while (data_size > 0)
    {
        int sent = send(sock_http, pdata, data_size, 0);
        if (sent == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "SOCKET FAILED IN SEND LOOP" << endl;
            break;
        }

        pdata += sent;
        data_size -= sent;
    } //SEND
    
    if (data_size <= 0) { all_sent = true; }
        
    if (all_sent)
    {
        ZeroMemory(bb_receive, 4096);
        int bytes_received = recv(sock_http, bb_receive, 4096, 0);
    
        if (bytes_received > 0)
        {
            cout << "Bytes received (Socket " << sock_http << "): " << bytes_received << endl;
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes_received; i++) { cout << bb_receive[i]; }
    } //RECEIVE
    
    return all_sent;
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA ws_data;
    WORD ws_version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int startup = WSAStartup(ws_version, &ws_data); if (startup != 0) { cout << "WSA FAILED" << endl; }

    sock_http = socket_create_http("domain.net", 443);

    bool success = http_post("action=0&data=0");

    cout << "WSA Last Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;

    closesocket(sock_http);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of `recv()` the server's response:

```
Bytes received (Socket 532): 4096
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Mon, 15 Aug 2022 18:23:43 GMT
Server: Apache
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade, close
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Kk. Paste ready!

Comment: Can you point your finger to the line of code that specifies the IP address that the socket connects to? No, that's not what `bind()` does.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you are not calling the [`connect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect) function to establish a connection to the HTTP server's IP/port. You are using the [`bind()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-bind) function instead, which merely establishes the socket's *local* IP/port, but you can't `bind()` a socket to a *remote* IP/Port.  That is what `connect()` is meant for.

When a socket function fails, use `WSAGetLastError()` to find out why. In your case, `send()` would be failing with a [`WSAENOTCONN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinSock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) error:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send

> **Return value**
>
> If no error occurs, send returns the total number of bytes sent, which can be less than the number requested to be sent in the len parameter. **Otherwise, a value of `SOCKET_ERROR` is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling `WSAGetLastError`.**
>
> | Error code | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... |
> | WSAENOTCONN | The socket is not connected. |
> | ... | ... |

That being said, there are many other issues with your code:

- you are not checking the return values of any of the system functions for failures.  `socket()` can fail. `gethostbyname()` can fail. And so on.  Always check return values before using any output.
- `gethostbyname()` has been deprecated for a long time. You really should be using [`getaddrinfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo) instead.
- what is `stuff:`? The first line of the HTTP request should look more like this instead:

  `POST /script.php HTTP/1.1\r\n`
- you are missing `Content-Type` and `Connection` headers in the HTTP request.
- you need to call `send()` in a loop, there is no guarantee it will be able to send the entire request in a single go. Pay attention to `send()`'s return value, it tells you how many bytes were actually sent. You will have to keep calling `send()` to re-send unsent bytes until there is nothing left to send.
- `strlen(request_string.c_str())` is redundant, use `request_string.size()` instead.
- consider using [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) instead of using a bunch of `std::string` concatenations.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

SOCKET socket_create_http(const char *hostname, unsigned short port)
{
    hostent* host = gethostbyname(hostname);
    if (host)
    {
        SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (sock != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr = {};
            SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            SockAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
            SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = * reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(host->h_addr);

            if (connect(sock, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
                return sock;

            closesocket(sock);
        }
    }

    /* alternatively:

    addrinfo hints = {};
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    addrinfo* addrs;
    
    if (getaddrinfo(hostname, to_string(port).c_str(), &hints, &addrs) == 0)
    {
        for (addrinfo* addr = addrs; addr != NULL; addr = addr->ai_next)
        {
            SOCKET sock = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
            if (sock != INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                if (connect(sock, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen) != SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    freeaddrinfo(addrs);
                    return sock;
                }

                closesocket(sock);
            }
        }

        freeaddrinfo(addrs);
    }

    */
    
    return INVALID_SOCKET;
}
    
bool sendAll(SOCKET sock, const void *data, size_t data_size)
{
    const char *pdata = static_cast<const char *>(data);

    while (data_size > 0)
    {
        int sent = send(sock, pdata, data_size, 0);
        if (sent == SOCKET_ERROR)
            return false;

        pdata += sent;
        data_size -= sent;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA ws_data;
    int startup = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &ws_data);
    if (startup != 0)
        return 1;

    SOCKET sock_http = socket_create_http("domain.net", 54000);
    if (sock_http == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    string data = "action=0&data=0";
            
    ostringstream request;
    request << "POST /script.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"; // or HTTP/1.0
    request << "Host: domain.net:54000\r\n";
    request << "Content-Length: " << data.size() << "\r\n";
    request << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    request << "Connection: close\r\n";
    request << "\r\n";
    request << data;
    
    string request_string = request.str();
    int sent = sendAll(sock_http, request_string.c_str(), request_string.size());
    cout << "SENT: " << sent << endl;

    closesocket(sock_http);

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for the detailed response! That works, and seems to create a socket and connect. I've tried to post and print the `recv()` results, which results in `400 bad request` and then spews out some of the website's html and css -- I've updated the post with the frankensteined code, and the recv() output.

Comment: @user19747167 please don't make edits to your question that invalidate existing comments/answers.  I have rolled back your edits and re-posted them correctly to preserve the integrity of the original question.  Additional details should be *added* as edits, but not *overwrite* the old details.

Comment: @user19747167 your new `socket_create_http()` has *undefined behavior* if a failure occurs, since you removed the final `return` statement, and it leaks the `SOCKET` if `connect()` fails. Also, you need to call `recv()` in a loop, just like with `send()`. And you can remove your entire `for` loop after `recv()` with a single `cout.write()` call instead...

Comment: @user19747167 ... But in any case, the `400` error has nothing to do with your socket handling, only with your HTTP request. Something is wrong with the `POST` request itself. For instance, you say "stuff is https", and HTTPS is just HTTP over an **encrypted** connection, but there is no SSL/TLS handling in this code at all to encrypt the data being transmitted over the socket. You *really* should not be implementing HTTP(S) from scratch at the WinSock layer, Windows has higher level WinInet/WinHTTP APIs that handle this stuff for you.

Comment: I know the error output sucks and the recv isn't formatted, I'm trying to get a bare bones POST to work in a blank project, before doing anything more reliable. Edit: The domain is mine, maybe I should just drop the SSL cert haha... Although, I guess encrypting user/pass stuff would be the right move? client --> server --> php_script --> SQL database

Comment: @user19747167 "*I'm trying to get a bare bones POST to work in a blank project*" - then either drop HTTPS and just use HTTP, or else drop WinSock and use WinInet/WinHTTP instead. There is nothing bare-bones about dealing with SSL/TLS encryption, it is complicated stuff.

Comment: This is wild! In a game engine I could post with two lines of code to HTTPS -- I've been spoiled. I guess my question is, with intentions to store user data in a database, I _should_ keep SSL and switch to WinInet/WinHTTP?

Comment: @user19747167 Whether or not you use [WinInet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/portal)/[WinHTTP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttp-start-page) has nothing to do with how the server uses the posted data. It doesn't know what you are using to implement your client. You could have used [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/) instead, for instance. The lesser code you want to write, the higher level you need to go, using wrapper APIs/libraries that handle the hard work for you. Using WinSock is fairly low-level, just above the raw networking layer.

Comment: I don't really mind staying lower level. Importing robust libraries stresses me out. And I'm just a hobbyist, so once data is flowing... It's done. And I can move on to the fun stuff ^^ That being said, it sounds like I should for this, so I'll just take a look at WinInet. Anyhow, thanks again for all the help.

Comment: @user19747167 "*I'll just take a look at WinInet*" - any further questions on that topic should be posted separately.

Comment: I didnt assume otherwise. O/

Comment: Side note, WinInet worked like a charm... Posted through the SSL, called back perfectly.